# Not able to call class method using Provider.of(context)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-provider

I am learning to use State Management and Provider package using this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: MyText(),
          ),
          body: Level1(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Level2(),
    );
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyTextField(),
        Level3(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data);
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data);
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newText) {
        print("onChanged Start");
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newText); //this line troubling me
        print("onChanged End");
      },
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  String data = "Some Data";

  void changeString(String newString) {
    print("changeString Start");
    print(newString + " changeString Text");
    data = newString;
    notifyListeners();
    print("changeString End");
  }
}
```

While Running the app, The AppBar Text `MyText()` and Level 3 Text `Text()` works fine.
as if I change the value of `data` in the code and Hot Restart the changes updated in `data` and also reflected in the app.

I also created `MyTextFiled()` where any changes occur it should get updated in `data` but the `changeString()` method is not getting called by the `Provider.of<Data>(context)` at line 64.

Here is the console output when I typed "Test" in the TextField.

```
onChange Start
t
onChange Start
te
onChange Start
tes
onChange Start
test
```

Expected was:

```
onChange Start
t
changeString Start
t changeString Text
changeString End
onChange End
(so on .....)
```

I am using `provider: ^4.1.2` and in the tutorial (which I am following), they use `provider: ^3.0.0+1`
So, I changed `builder` to `create` in line 10, as it was showing error.

My Flutter Version:

```
Flutter 1.17.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e6b34c2b5c (4 weeks ago) • 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
Engine • revision 540786dd51
Tools • Dart 2.8.1
```

PS: My problem get solved when I replace `Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newText);` with `context.read<Data>().changeString(newText);` with the help of this example [Provider Example](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-example-tab-)

But I am not able to understand why Provider.of(context) didn't work but context.read() work.
Please, enlighten me with the explanation.

I apologize for asking a dumb question on this sacred community. 
and Thank you for listening/reading my problem carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your  TextField's onChanged function like this:

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newText) {
        print("onChanged Start");
        Provider.of<Data>(context,listen:false).changeString(newText); //notice , listen default value is true
        print("onChanged End");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

you are right about `context.read<Data>()` but you should know that `context.read<T>()` is equivalent to `Provider.of<T>(context,listen:false)`

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value) =>

- `context.watch<T>()`  is the same as `Provider.of<T>(context)` or `Provider.of<T>(context,listen:true)` because listen is true by default
- `context.read<T>()`  is the same as `Provider.of<T>(context,listen:false)`